# Queueing a Series of State Updates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  function clickHandler() {
    setNumber((n) => {
      console.log('First updater function');
      return n + 1;
    });
    setNumber((n) => {
      console.log('Second updater function');
      return n + 1;
    });
    console.log('Other code in the click handler');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Increment number</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

According to this page, https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates,

> The function passed to state setter is called an updater function. React queues the updater function to be processed after all the other code in the event handler has run. During the next render, React goes through the queue and gives you the final updated state.

From the above statement, I understand that, when I click the button, console.log should appear in the below order:

1. Other code in the click handler
2. First updater function
3. Second updater function

However, the logs are displayed in the below order:

1. First updater function
2. Other code in the click handler
3. Second updater function

The above order was observed when I click the button first time only. Clicking the button second time or more, again the order changes as expected:

1. Other code in the click handler
2. First updater function
3. Second updater function

So I was wondering why it was behaving differently when clicking the button first time and that behaviour also not matching as stated in the above React documentation page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `useState` hook in React follows a **synchronous state update mechanism**. When you call `setNumber` in your event handler, it's invoking the `updater function` immediately, instead of queuing it for later execution.

That's why you're seeing the console log from the **first updater function** immediately when you click the button. After the first `setNumber` is processed, the control returns to your event handler, and it logs 'Other code in the click handler', then it processes the second `setNumber` call, hence the console log from the `second updater function`.

The difference in behavior you're noticing between the `first click` and `subsequent clicks` is due to **React's batched update mechanism**. On the `first click`, since the component is not in a batched update phase, each `setNumber` call is processed immediately and separately. However, on subsequent clicks, React has entered a **batched update phase**, so all state updates within the event handler are batched together and applied at once at the end of the event, which aligns with your expected console log order.

###### This is a simple demonstration of how you might implement a simplified version of this mechanism in JavaScript:

```js
let state;  // Current state
let updates = [];  // Queue of updates
let isBatching = false;  // Check if batching is enabled

function useState(initialValue) {
  // Initialize the state
  if (state === undefined) {
    state = initialValue;
  }

  function setState(update) {
    if (isBatching) {
      // If we're in a batching phase, queue the update
      updates.push(update);
    } else {
      // If not, apply the update immediately
      state = update(state);
      render();
    }
  }

  return [state, setState];
}

function flushUpdates() {
  // Apply all updates
  for (let update of updates) {
    state = update(state);
  }
  // Clear the updates queue
  updates = [];
  render();
}

// A simple render function
function render() {
  console.log(`Rendered with state: ${state}`);
}

function clickHandler(setNumber) {
  isBatching = true;
  // Queue two updates
  setNumber((n) => {
    console.log('First updater function');
    return n + 1;
  });
  setNumber((n) => {
    console.log('Second updater function');
    return n + 1;
  });
  console.log('Other code in the click handler');

  // Then flush the updates
  flushUpdates();
  isBatching = false;
}

// Usage:
let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
clickHandler(setNumber);  // It will log 'First updater function', 'Second updater function', 'Other code in the click handler', 'Rendered with state: 2'
```

### Note

As an end-user of React, you're not supposed to depend on these implementation details. Your component should not rely on the exact order of state updates within a single event handler because it could be subject to change in future versions of React.

Answer (score 0):

The **short answer** is probably:
That sentence *(currently: ["React queues this function to be processed after all the other code in the event handler has run"](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#updating-the-same-state-multiple-times-before-the-next-render))* is indeed probably not 100% true.

The React developers still always work on React and try to optimize things as far as possible, considering different edge cases,
probably sometimes accepting tradeoffs, which makes it less straight-forward to describe what is going on.

I can imagine that that sentence was true at some point, but optimizations might have been implemented in the meantime,
which make the sentence un-true for some cases.

This detail is probably rarely relevant, but I agree that if the documentation makes a statement like this, you should be allowed to rely on it.

So the documentation should maybe:

- either add something like *"... except for some optimizations"*,
- or alternative it should not mention a specific call order at all,
  if React considers this an implementation detail, and doesn't want you to rely on it.

#### Analysis

*I have to guess here. I found some hints that might explain what is going on, but I might be totally wrong.
Also React might have changed since version 18.2.0 which I am currently using.*

React needs the resulting state only in the next render cycle, not in the current one. So I understand that in some cases, when there are
no other reasons to re-render, and the state has not changed, React decides to skip the next render cycle altogether, as a performance optimization.
But *to know* that the state hasn't changed, it needs to call the updater function.

Note that if the first updater function doesn't change the state, then even the second updater function gets called before the other code in the event handler (again only when
called the first time):

```
function clickHandler() {
    setNumber((n) => {
        console.log('First updater function');
        return n + 0;   // <--- state is not changed
    });
    setNumber((n) => {
        console.log('Second updater function');
        return n + 1;
    });
    console.log('Other code in the click handler');
}
```

Results in the console output:

```
First updater function
Second updater function
Other code in the click handler
```

In the React source code, in the [`dispatchSetState`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L2983) function,
there is [a note](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L3017) that might be related:

```
// The queue is currently empty, which means we can eagerly compute the  
// next state before entering the render phase. If the new state is the  
// same as the current state, we may be able to bail out entirely.
```